# What is the answer of 1.01010x2^4 + 1.00111x2^6?

Tags: floating-point

I'm korean. So please understand my poor English.
I'm learning floating point single precision.

Also, I learned addition of floating point numbers.

But, I didn't understand about guard bit and round bit.

What I want to ask is this problem.

"Add 1.01010*2^4 + 1.00111*2^6

Do we need guard/round bit? Assume significand is 5-bits long"

So I calculated this and result was 1.1000110*2^6.

From this, last 2-bit "10" is guard/round bit which must be rounded?

or Do I have to truncate those bits?

How to I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

When doing floating-point arithmetic by hand you don't have to think about guard, round, or sticky bits. On paper, you have unlimited precision, so just keep all the bits as you unnormalize, perform the operation, and normalize. Then just round that full-precision result to the desired place.

The normalized result in your case is 1.100011*2^6. It has one bit too many, so it needs to be rounded to the 5th place (you said the significand is 5-bits long but it is really 6, with one to the left of the point); the result is 1.1001*2^6.

(If you need to do it on paper like you were a machine then you'd have to simulate those extra bits.)